# WSGIServer not working with https and python3

Tags: python-3.x, wsgi, gevent

We got a old package write in python2, and working on upgrade it to python3. It's a web app and we are using the WSGIServer.

```
from gevent import pywsgi
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', port), apphandler, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)

def apphandler(request, start_response):
    log.info("ATTENTION: request is {}".format(request))
    # do something
```

However, when I try to use the web app with https://website, it would show this error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
website.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

And in my server log, I would see things like:

```
Invalid HTTP method: '\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01ü\x03\x03Èæ\x01\x92É\x16ÁW»P½\x1aBÐa\x83ÆÊa]ãíDp¥¥¥\x12Ç\x82|\x1f E5\x03aAv\x99¢Nª\x93ÅÏ:Ð\x9d÷3£\x80çÍïÌÑÿC\rÏUÄ\x8b\x00 ªª\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x93ZZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x003\x00\x000website.com\x00\x17\x00\x00ÿ\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\n'
```

When I actually use the website as http://website.com, it would work. And when in python2, the server would respond correctly to https.

I'm guessing it might be encoding issue, but it won't even reach where I put log in apphandler function. Does anyone know how am I possible to fix this? Do I need to change server or python3 encoding setup?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are starting up a plain TCP web server sitting on port 443 and then hitting it from a web browser using an https: url.

If you check out the documentation:

https://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.pywsgi.html#gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer

You need to supply `ssl_args` in order to get the socket to run under SSL instead of TCP. Just supplying a port number of 443 is not sufficient.

You can find a few examples of how to set ssl_args here:

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/78007/gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer